# Service in constructor

Tags: php, laravel, service

I have a method that handles the processing (update/store) form where I need to use the service. If I was using only the method itself. I would do it like this:

```
public function update($id, SalesForceApiService $sf) {
    ...
}
public function update($id, SalesForceApiService $sf) {
    ...
}
```

But in my case, I am using another method to handle processing the form:

```
protected function processForm($mode, $id = null) {
    dd($this->sf);
    ...
}
```

I am wondering, how should I pass the service into the `processForm` method. Should I call it in the update and the store method and then pass to the `processForm()`? Or can I declare the `SalesForceApiService` in the constructor of controller and then access it via `$this->sf` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `processForm()` is in the controller, inject it via the constructor or manually using the [`app()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-app) or [`resolve()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-resolve) helpers:

```
$saleForceSevice = app('SalesForceApiService');
$saleForceSevice = resolve('SalesForceApiService');
```

Comment: Alexey's answer will do the trick, also make sure you've registered it inside of `register` in your `AppServiceProvider` so you will be able to inject it, you can do so with a method `bind`

Comment: well, so I can access the methods from the service like so?
`$sf = app(SalesForceApiService::class);   
        dd($sf->sendDonor());`

Comment: @Epsilon47 yes, you can.

Answer (score 2):

Like Alexey already suggested and only to make you understand how you can do it please take a look at this controller example:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    private $salesForceApiService;

    public function __construct(SalesForceApiService  $salesForceApiService)
    {
        $this->salesForceApiService = $salesForceApiService;
    }

    public function updateSimple($id)
    {
        $this->processForm('simple', $id);
    }

    public function updateComplex($id)
    {
        $this->processForm('complex', $id);
    }

    private function processForm($mode, $id = null)
    {
        $this->salesForceApiService
            ->setMode($mode)
            ->something($id);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this one and it worked as well. I use to set `repositories` in the constructor method but I have not tried it with services yet. I just did not know if it is the best practise, because then the service will be initilalized always, even in the methods where I don't need it. But maybe that does not matter?

Comment: Even if you don't use that service the resources spent to instantiate it are really insignificant. However, both practices are ok, the only condition being to use DI container to inject it (it's recommended for testing purposes)

Comment: Yes, I thought so. But I did not know about the testing purposes. That may save me some time in the future when it will come to tests, it is really the future where they are needed. Thanks